# Gulp: deploying folders and files

Tags: gulp

I only get files copied with this

```
gulp.task('deploy', function() {
    gulp.src(['dist/**/*'], { base : '.' })
        .pipe(scp({
            host: 'some_IP',
            user: 'some_user',
            port: some_port,
            path: 'some_folder'
        }));
});
```

I am missing all the folder structure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: read [this](http://www.levihackwith.com/how-to-make-gulp-copy-a-directory-and-its-contents/) it should help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have changed base to 'dist' although still getting same wrong result.

Comment: interesting, what version of gulp are you using?

Comment: hmmm looks like the plugin itself has issues dealing with folder structure. Try using [rsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rsync)? It can specifically copy directories files / directories recursively.

Comment: I have switched to scp2 plugin. Now I am getting just a couple of folders copied. This is so strange. Should I still use rsync?

Comment: it certainly is odd, i'd probably give rsync a go, if you're on windows sometimes these things can be a little finicky.

Comment: I tried it out, same result as with scp2. I am on Mac.

Comment: Tried to copy it also with scp through terminal, everything works.

Comment: Using rsync instead of scp is much faster when you have more than just a couple of files. Here is an [example gulp script using rsync](https://silvantroxler.ch/2015/deployment-with-gulp-and-rsync/).